# Is it possible to detach Hibernate entity, so that changes to object are not automatically saved to database?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have Hibernate entity that I have to convert to JSON, and I have to translate some values in entity, but when I translate values, these values are instantly saved to database, but I don't want to save these changes to database. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can detach an entity by calling [`Session.evict()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29).

Other options are create a defensive copy of your entity before translation of values, or use a DTO instead of the entity in that code. I think these options are more elegant since they don't couple conversion to JSON and persistence layer.

Comment: In case of JPA, you can use:
[`EntityManager.detach(object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I was always using DTO for this purpose. Using defensive copy is good idea but the maintenance becomes tougher as down the year, people think the new object is a managed one but in realy it is actualy a local copy.

Answer (score 4):

I am also converting hibernate entities to JSON.

The bad thing when you close the session you cannot lazy load objects. For this reason you can use

```
hSession.setDefaultReadOnly(true);
```

and close the session after when you're done with the JSON.

Comment: This one should be voted the best answer, as it only does the bare minimum to solve the issue without affecting the entire session. To make the answer even more specific: `hSession.setReadOnly(myObject, true);`

Answer (score 3):

You can also avoid that your entities are attached to the Hibernate Session by using a `StatelessSession`:

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
```

instead of

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Note that you must take care yourself of closing the `StatelessSession`, unlike the regular Hibernate Session:

```
session.close(); // do this after you are done with the session
```

Another difference compared to the regular Session is that a `StatelessSession` can not fetch collections. I see it's main purpose for data-fetching-only `SQLQuery` stuff.

You can read more about the different session types here:

http://www.interviewadda.com/difference-between-getcurrentsession-opensession-and-openstatelesssession/

Answer (score 1):

Close the Session.  That will detach your entity for you, and no modifications will be flushed.  If that's not possible, look into disabling autoFlush...but that's a whole other can of worms.  The easiest is to close the Session and be done with it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just flushed and cleared the session.

session.flush();
session.clear();

Answer (score -1):

```
public static <E> E deepClone(E e) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oo;
    try {
        oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
        oo.writeObject(e);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(bo.toByteArray());
    ObjectInputStream oi;
    try {
        oi = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
        return (E) (oi.readObject());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

first: deepClone the session pojo
second: alter fields
then: do whatever you want to do