# transient domain instance jpa&spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

My domain objects are roughly like:

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Account> accountList;
}

@Entity
public class Account{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Service> serviceList;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private Customer customer;
}

@Entity
public class Service{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private Account account;
}
```

I have a transactional Spring service. I want to return an Account instance to fronthand but I don't want to send Customer and Service List informations because of bandwith issues.

When I do:
account.setServiceList(null);
It gives no error but after a while it deletes all my service list.

When I do:
account.setCustomer(null);
It says customer_id of account cannot be null.

I just want to return a transient instance without a validation. How can I handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The solution to your problem is to make the entity detached, by calling `entityManager.detach(accountInstance)` (or `entityManager.clear()` if you use JPA 1.0 to detach all entities) and only THAN change anything to it. If you use Hibernate's sessions, use the [Session.evict()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
2. The other solution is to use a DTO, something that has only the fields that you need.

PS: I think you have an bug, in which the bidirectional relationships are missing on one side the `mapped` property. E.g in `Customer` you should have something like

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customer")
private List<Account> accountList;
```

The same with the other relationship.

Comment: First of all thanks for this quick answer. about mappedBy, I have them, but I have forgotten to write it here. about detach, it seems it is what I needed but the problem is that I don't use entityManager, I use sessionFactory. Is there any similar thing for org.hibernate.sessionfactory too?

Comment: Yes, of course you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800814/is-it-possible-to-detach-hibernate-entity-so-that-changes-to-object-are-not-aut I updated a bit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: At the moment I can't test since our server is down :( but be sure that I'll accept if this work.