# Session Cache and Update/Merge Methods

Tags: java, hibernate, session, caching

It's well explained in blogs such as [[1]](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/difference-between-update-vs-merge-example.html) that update() and merge() methods may behave differently in case we need to update some detached entity. On the other hand, blog [[2]](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/understanding-hibernate-first-level-cache-with-example/) states:

> First level cache is associated with “session” object and other session objects in application can not see it.The scope of cache objects is of session. **Once session is closed, cached objects are gone forever.**

Here's a code snippet from reference [[1](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/difference-between-update-vs-merge-example.html)]:

```
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Student student = (Student) session.get(Student.class, 111);
    session.close();

    student.setName("chandrashekhar");

    Session session2 = factory.openSession();
    Student student2 = session2.get(Student.class, 111); //a new Student object with id=111
    Transaction tx = session2.beginTransaction();
    session2.update(student); //throws NonUniqueObjectExcpetion because there's already *student2* in session2 cache
    tx.commit();
```

Here's my question: `session` and `session2` are two different `Session` objects. why does `update()` method throw a `NonUniqueObjectExcpetion` while by closing the object `session` it should've destroyed the object `student`? (thus we couldn't have encountered such an exception.)

Comment: What kind of exception are you encountering?

Comment: @MichielLeegwater if there's another entity object with the same id, then we will get NonUniqueObjectException.

Comment: Does this article help understand the issue? https://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-session-merge-vs-update-save-saveorupdate-persist-example

Comment: Another hunch might be that the session is closed, but the object that is loaded still considers itself attached. To sort that out the object needs detaching. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800814/is-it-possible-to-detach-hibernate-entity-so-that-changes-to-object-are-not-aut